# Webstorm JSON minifier plugin/file watcher

Tags: json

I'm working with WebStorm 8.0.4 from jetBrain.

We are manually editing a JSON file for the labels i18n. This file has the indents and the tabs. I would like to have it minify automatically, with a file watcher. Has anyone created a plugin or created the right file watcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [json-minify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/json-minify):

- `npm install -g json-minify`
- create a new file watcher in WebStorm, like:

  **Program**: /path/to/json-minify/exec, like C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\npm\json-minify.cmd

  **Arguments**: $FileName$

  **Working dir**: $FileDir$

  **Output paths to refresh**: $FileNameWithoutExtension$.minified.json

Make sure to tick '**Create output file from stdout**' checkbox

Comment: Note that nodejs needs to be installed, and webstorm rebooted if nodejs was installed while webstorm was running.